# Moisture Holding Capacity of Air table or function?

Tags: thermodynamics

It is strange but I cannot find the good table of Moisture Holding Capacity of Air g/kg or lb/lb like the chart here:
https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/moisture-holding-capacity-air-d_281.html
[image]

I am trying to make calculations in MS Excel visual basic module, I have the absolute humidity and need to get the relative humidity for given temperature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If A is the absolute humidity(in mass of water vapor per mass of dry air), the moles of water vapor per mole of dry air is $$m=\frac{29}{18}A$$The mole fraction of water vapor in the in the air is $$x=\frac{m}{(m+1)}=\frac{29A}{29A+18}$$If $p_{atm}$ is the current atmospheric pressure, then the partial pressure of water vapor in the air is $$p=xp_{atm}=\frac{29A}{29A+18}p_{atm}$$The relative humidity is the partial pressure divided by the equilibrium vapor pressure of water vapor at the temperature T ($p_{vap,eq}$) times 100 %:$$RH=100\left(\frac{29A}{29A+18}\right)\frac{p_{atm}}{p_{vap,eq}}$$

Answer (score 2):

The maximum amount of water that air can hold is given by the Antoine equation for water.  For a given temperature, when the partial pressure of water vapor in air is equal to its vapor pressure, the air is at 100% humidity.  Note that the calculation will normally be on a molar basis, so there is a conversion involved if you want to convert to kg water vapor per kg of dry air.

For more information on the Antoine equation, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine_equation

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/relhum.html) offers 
a pair of formulas of "Empirical fit of saturated vapor density versus Celsius Temperature". For T in 0..40°C you can use `5.02 + 0.323*T + 8.18e-3*T^2 + 3.12e-4*T^3`, where T is measured in Celcius (this is an approximation and I've eliminated significant digits that have no visible effect on a high-resolution chart.)

Answer (score 0):

tables of functions like these are available in any textbook dealing with the discipline of *heating/ventilating/air conditioning* (a.k.a. "HVAC") engineering.